# files_per_partitions keyword in dask.bag.read_text

Tags: python, dask, dask-distributed

I am not sure how to interpret the files_per_partitions keyword in dask.bag.read_text.

1. As described [here](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-best-practices.html), a Dask DataFrame is split up into many Pandas DataFrames, which are referred to as “partitions”. What is the meaning of "partition" in files_per_partitions (in dask.bag.read_text) instead?
2. What is the optimal value for files_per_partitions? I can see that if files_per_partitions is too high, then my dask.distributed workers run out of memory, and a KilledWorked error is raised (see code below for an example, and notice that each worker has a memory limit of 2.43 GiB).

```
import json
import dask.bag as db
from dask.distributed import Client

client = Client(n_workers=4)

def process_dict(dict_):
    # This returns a list of dicts

bag = db.read_text(
    "local_directory/*.json",  # 7300 json files with size 70KB each (0.511GB in total)
    linedelimiter="\n}\n}",  
    files_per_partition=200,  # If >3000, KilledWorker is raised when executing compute() below
    )
bag = bag.map(json.loads).map(process_dict).flatten()

df = bag.to_dataframe()
pandas_df = df.repartition(npartitions=5).groupby("column_1").agg({
    "column_2":"mean",
    "column_3":"mean",
    "column_4":"sum"
}).compute()
```

Answer (score 1):

The [source](https://github.com/dask/dask/blob/c5633c21e754df6b2c13195f1e2688e347c48963/dask/bag/text.py) has a comment with an explanation:

> files_per_partition: None or int
> If set, group input files into partitions of the requested size,
> instead of one partition per file. Mutually exclusive with blocksize.

Later on in the source code (line 107), you'll see:

```
if files_per_partition is None:
   <blocks becomes a list of lists of size 1 each>
else:
   <blocks becomes a list of lists of size files_per_partition each>
```

The optimal value is system-dependent, and is basically as large a value as you can get away with depending your memory capacity and the distribution of file sizes in your folder. If your largest file is too large, you'll need to use `blocksize` to break it up.